# Clarification on a potential typo in a theorem from Garnett's Bounded Analytic Functions (2007)

Tags: harmonic-functions

**Theorem 6.5** from Garnett's 2007 book [*Bounded Analytic Functions*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-49763-3) is as follows. I quote it verbatim, because I am concerned about the possibility of there being a typo:

> **Theorem 6.5.** Let $v\left(z\right)$ be a subharmonic function in the unit disk $D$. Assume $v(z)\not\equiv-\infty$. For $0<r<1$, let $$v_{r}(z)=\begin{cases}
> v(z), & \lvert z\rvert\leq r,\\
> \frac{1}{2\pi}\int P_{z/r}(\theta)v(re^{i\theta})\mathrm d\theta, & \lvert z\rvert<r.
> \end{cases}$$
> Then $v_{r}(z)$ is a subharmonic function in $D$, $v_{r}(z)$ is harmonic on $\lvert z\rvert<r$, $v_{r}(z)\geq v(z)$, $z\in D$, and $v_{r}(z)$ is an increasing function of $r$.

Am I correct in assuming that the second condition $\lvert z\rvert<r$ in the definition of $v_{r}(z)$ is incorrect, and that it should read $r<\lvert z\rvert<1$? If so, please include "Yes, you are correct" in your response. If am not correct, please include "No, you are incorrect" in your response and tell me exactly how I am supposed to interpret  this result. This detail is very important for my research, so I want to make sure I get it exactly right.

Comment: I bet that the *first* condition ("$|z| \leqslant r$") should read "$r \leqslant |z| < 1$".

Comment: you are not correct as the second part is correct since that implies by the subharmonicity of $v$ that $v(z) \le v_r(z), |z|<r$ (which is what we want from later text) hence the first part must be indeed $v_r=v, r \le |z| <1$ as @Mateusz also noted

Comment: Thanks a bunch!